# [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, tls1.2, rest, ioerror

I'm new in python and unfortunately I've already tried everything by copying the cacert.pem file from / lib / site-packages / certifi to / lib / site-packages / requests and then with overriding this function and overriding the variables set by this function to fix the problem. Unfortunately it didn't work. I apologize for my bad english and maybe for stupid questions, but unfortunately I can't find a suitable solution or use it correctly. Thanks so much!

```
  I got this error:
```

```
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/X/X/X.py", line 37, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=body, verify='False')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 416, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 227, in cert_verify
    raise IOError("Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, "
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: False
```

```
 my code for rest api:
```

````
payload  = {}
headers = dict(Authorization='Bearer '
                             'jwt=TOKEN..')

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify='False')

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))```
````

Comment: `verify=False` is the bool value and means don't verify the server; `verify='False'` is a _string_ value and means verify using the contents of a _file or directory_ named `False` and you don't have such a file or dir. `verify=True` (bool) _or_ omitted means verify using the _default_ location, which automatically uses certifi without you doing anything to 'help'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 if i romoved verify , i got this: Traceback self.connect() self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock, 500, in wrap_socket return self.sslsocket_class._create( self.do_handshake() self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)

Answer (score 0):

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/

I solved by add cert

````
payload  = {}
headers = dict(Authorization='Bearer '
                             'jwt=TOKEN..')

response = requests.get(url,cert=('client.crt', 'client.pem.txt'), verify=False headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))```
````